# Saving a record that relies on two tables

Tags: controller, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

Working on my first rails app.
I have two models: Albums and Tracks.

When adding a track to an album, I need the album ID in order to save.
I have a collection_select that pulls all the albums and lists them with their IDs in descending order:

`<%= form.collection_select :albums_id, Album.all.order(id: :desc), :id, :title, :include_blank => false %>`

This works fine, creating the html:

```
<select name="track[albums_id]" id="track_albums_id">
  <option value="11">Eleventh Album Title</option>
  <option value="10">Tenth Album Title</option>
  ...
</select>
```

But when I try to save the new record, I always get the error:
`Album must exist`

The controller has:

```
 def create
   @track = Track.new(track_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @track.save
       format.html { redirect_to @track, notice: 'Track added.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @track }
     else
       @page_title = 'ERROR - Add Track'
       format.html { render :new }
       format.json { render json: @track.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

and `track_params` refers to:

```
private
  def track_params
    params.require(:track).permit(:albums_id, :title, :track_number, :track_url)
  end
```

Models:

album.rb

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :tracks
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :release_year, presence: true
    has_one_attached :photo
end
```

track.rb

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :album
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :track_number, presence: true
    validates :track_url, presence: true
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tracks
  root 'pages#about'

  get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
  get 'contact', to: 'messages#new', as: 'contact'
  get 'sessions', to: 'sessions#new'
  get 'dashboard', to: 'pages#dashboard', as: 'dashboard'

  resources :videos
  resources :gigs
  resources :photos
  resources :albums
  resources :users
  resources :groups
  resources :messages
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  post "/delayed_job" => DelayedJobWeb, :anchor => false
end
```

All the values except `:albums_id` are accepted. The selected value in the collection_select is always ignored and triggers the error that prevents saving the track.
`albums_id` is the database column name, created by rails as a result of `belongs_to: albums`.

What am I doing badly?

*UPDATE: Migrations*

...create_albums.rb:

```
class CreateAlbums < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :albums do |t|
      t.string :artist
      t.string :copyright
      t.string :title
      t.date :release_year
      t.text :comment

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

...create_tracks.rb:

```
class CreateTracks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :tracks do |t|
      t.belongs_to :albums
      t.string :title
      t.integer :track_number, :default => 1
      t.string :track_url

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you associating the records somewhere? Please show your model files and your routes.rb file.

Comment: @hashrocket Added to question.

Comment: Are you sure the database column is called `albums_id`. It looks like it should be called `album_id`.

Comment: It is definitely called albums_id. I checked in mysql CLI, plus if I try it without the pluralized word, I get `unknown column` type error.

Comment: Can you paste the database migration file of albums and tracks? Ideally your Models should b singular, so you generate models like rails g model Album and rails g model Track in turn rails create plural db tables which are tracks and albums. There must be some issue in your migration files. Please share that

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal Added migrations.

Comment: @Kane Your association in the migration if it just had t.belongs_to :album it would have worked for you properly. Check th answer and see if this works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is follow rails convention, instead of working around it.
You can drop the column of albums_id (There is a way to make this work, but again its a work around and not advisable) so, instead yiu can first drop the column albums_id and then add album_id like below:

```
rails g migration DropColumnFromTrack
```

Then in the generated migration file:

```
remove_column :tracks, :albums_id
```

Then do: (Assuming that you have no data in this column)

```
rails db:migrate
```

Now generate the album_id column:
Here below album:references means we are telling that the record in track table belongs to the album table.

```
rails g migration AddAlbumToTrack album:references
```

And do

```
rails db:migrate
```

Ensure that you have an album_id column in your tracks table and now the associations should work properly

Comment: I don't know why album_id had been created as albums_id, but thank you kindly for this step by step. It works perfectly now. Just taking me a while to get my head around how everything works. :) Thank you. :)

Comment: I would say try to read up on rails models association especially the difference between singular and plural in models. Take your time in understanding this, it will save you a lot of time in future.

Comment: Yes, I have a lot to learn. These mistakes will ultimately help me to understand. :)